# how to post comment on content in php while loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have a page where all post are shown by php while loop like this->

```
Post 1
here is post 1 comment form

Post 2
here is comment form 2
```

here is the html part

```
php while loop starts here
<div id="tickers"> </div>
<form action="#" class="form-horizontal inner-all" id="show<?php echo $id; ?>">

 <input name="mesgid" type="hidden" id="mesgid" value="<?php echo $id ?>">

<input name="usernames" id="usernames" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $usermsg ?>">

<input class="form-control" type="text" name="com" id="com" placeholder="Respond with a comment...">

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-theme tyiop" id="data<?php echo $id;?>"></button>

   </form>
   php while loop ends here
```

here is the jquery part

```
   <script>
$(function() {
$(".tyiop").click(function()
{
var mesgid = $("#mesgid").val();
var usernames = $("#usernames").val();
var comment = $("#com").val();
var dataString = 'mesgid='+ mesgid + '&usernames=' + usernames + '&comment=' + comment;
if(mesgid=='' || usernames=='' || comment=='')
{
alert('Please Give Valid Details');
}
else
{
$(".flasher").show();
$(".flasher").fadeIn(400).html('Loading Comment...');
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "ajax/commentor.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html){
$("#tickers").append(html);
$("#flasher").hide();
}
});
}return false;
}); });
</script>
```

Whenever i click on post comment the comment is appended to other post div, how can append the data only on that on which i posted

Comment: <div id="tickers"> </div> is in the loop. so how can you manage if id is the same??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use like this, here i am taking the reference of clicked element:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$(".tyiop").click(function()
{
var container  = this;
var mesgid = $("#mesgid").val();
var usernames = $("#usernames").val();
var comment = $("#com").val();
var dataString = 'mesgid='+ mesgid + '&usernames=' + usernames + '&comment=' + comment;
if(mesgid=='' || usernames=='' || comment=='')
{
alert('Please Give Valid Details');
}
else
{
$(".flasher").show();
$(".flasher").fadeIn(400).html('Loading Comment...');
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "ajax/commentor.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html){
$(container).parent('form').prev("#tickers").append(html);
$("#flasher").hide();
}
});
}return false;
}); });
</script>
```

Comment: it is not appending any data to the div

Comment: Can you tell me if i make <div id=tickers427></div> and write in jquery $('#tickers'+mesgid).append(html); will it work? but when i alert it, show object object